# Mysql: Select tables have different relations and get a result even some of them missing

Tags: mysql

There is 4 tables that apresent `products`, `sub_cat_products`, `sold_products` and `sub_sold` some of products dosn't have `sub_cat_products` then when I join them using `Where` and `AND` I miss the product is sold that hasn't `sub_cat_products`.
how can solve it?

**tables:**

```
products
========
id_product | desc1
1 | product 1
2 | product 2

sub_cat_products
========
id_sub_cat_products | id_product | desc2
1 | 1 | sub_product 1 
2 | 1 | sub_product 1
3 | 1 | sub_product 3

sold_products
========
id_sold_products | id_product | qtd
1 | 1 | 100
2 | 1 | 50

sub_sold
========
id_sub_sold | id_sold_products | id_sub_cat_products | qtd
1 | 1 | 1 | 30
2 | 1 | 2 | 40
3 | 1 | 3 | 30
```

**Mysql:**

```
SELECT * form products,sub_cat_products, sold_products, sub_sold
WHERE sold_products.id_sold_products = sub_sold.id_sold_products
AND sold_products.id_product = products.id_product
AND sub_cat_products.id_sub_cat_products = sub_sold.id_sub_cat_products
```

Comment: Just use`OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Please add the desired result.

Comment: This may work: `SELECT * form 
  products
 Left Join sub_cat_products
 on  products.id_products = sub_cat_products.id_products
inner join sub_sold
on sub_sold.id_products = products.id_products
inner join sold_products
 on sold_products.id_sold_products = sub_sold.id_sold_products;
`